# load bitmap image on ImageView android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have created a bitmap image.

e.g. scaled image

```
scaledVertical = scaleBitmap(verticalBmp, 50);
```

now i want to load it onto an ImageView.

e.g.

```
ImageView first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first);
```

i use

```
Drawable verticalImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scaledVertical);
ImageView first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first);
first.setBackground(verticalImage);
```

What is the right way to load bitmap image on image view ?

Comment: You are better off loading the image from its source, as a scaled bitmap, than load it then scale it. to save memory usage.

Comment: use setImageDrawable instead of setBackground

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
Drawable verticalImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scaledVertical);
ImageView first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first);
first.setImageDrawable(verticalImage);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you shouldn't use the ImageView method setBitmap(Bitmap bm)?

Comment: setBitmap does not exist, it's setImageBitmap.

In this case, verticalImage is a Drawable, but it is quite possible to use a bitmap.